# Not able to launch another component in react. passing values as params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, user-interface, react-router

I am calling another from current component

```
<Link to={`/${props.certificate.id}/edit` } >Edit</Link>
```

in the receiving component I am receiving it using props.

```
export function EditCertificate(props: any)
```

then I am accepting `id` as

```
const {id} = props.match.params;
```

so in the `url` below is coming but `EditCertificate` component is not getting launched.

http://localhost:4200/934108e0-ca73-4837-bbf2-26482ece1cb6/edit

in the route I have defined below.

```
<SecureRoute path=":id/edit">
  <EditCertificate id={":id"} />
</SecureRoute>;
```

what mistake I am doing?

Comment: Why are you passing ID as  <EditCertificate id={':id'} />
Instead pass it as  <EditCertificate id={id} />

Comment: If I do this it says  "Cannot find name 'id'."